# Format WCF Response

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a object return in a WCF and when I do an xml over http the response will look like:

```
<person>
  <name>Hello</name>
</person
```

I need it to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pre:person>
  <name>Hello</name>
</pre:person>
```

Is there an easy way to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Glance over this article it may help you [Changing prefixes in XML responses for WCF services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx).

Or you can try to return `XElement`.